# custom HttpResponse after a POST from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, post, httpresponse

I have a class that perfom a POST to a php page, this page should make some action with the posted data, and return the result (something like OK, KO). how can I send the result back in PHP, and how I use it in android?

on the Android side i've got this, which post the data:

```
public int postData(String id, String webrispid, String userid) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.server.com/postpage.php");
            int responseCode = 0;
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));               
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userid));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("webrisid", webrispid));
                try {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",AeSimpleSHA1.SHA1(userid) ));
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println(response);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            return responseCode;
        }
```

and actually the postpage.php looks like this:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['user']) ) {
// try to store the data posted

//if data is stored return "ok"

// else return "ko"

} else {
// error
}
?>
```

so on the android side, i should stop sending the same data and start process the rest of data and eventually send it to the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just 'OK' or 'KO', you could do the following:

```
<?php
  if ( isset($_POST['user']) ) { // try to store the data posted
    //do some test
    echo "OK"; //or KO
  } else { 
    echo "ERROR"; 
  }
?>
```

The android part could look like this:

```
// Execute HTTP Post Request
String status = httpclient.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
System.out.println(status); //will be OK or KO or ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

when you return from PHP file at the end of the action use

```
echo  json_encode("return status or some specific value");`
```

On the Android side, parse that `json` to get the status result.

Answer (score 0):

see this:

```
public int postData(String id, String webrispid, String userid) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.server.com/postpage.php");
        int responseCode = 0;
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));               
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", userid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("webrisid", webrispid));
            try {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",AeSimpleSHA1.SHA1(userid) ));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

                    String status = jObj.getString("status");   




    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }




        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return responseCode;
    }
```

here the "status" is the jsonObject returned from the php file using echo json_encode() function.